# conky Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: conky, segmentation-fault

I installed the new ubuntu 12.04 and i like it very much, but conky is giving me some problems

sometimes it is working normal, and the the next second conky is gone,
when i try to restart,

i get this:

```
$ conky
Conky: desktop window (c00021) is subwindow of root window (15d)
Conky: window type - desktop
Conky: drawing to created window (0x2a00001)
Conky: drawing to double buffer
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

does anyone know what i can do about that

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in 12.04 and it has to do with your computer's uptime. Please see this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/conky/+bug/1003727 and subscribe to it if you believe you experience the same thing.
What you can do is to downgrade conky!

Answer (score 0):

Does conky disappear when you click the desktop? That was the issue I was having. It stopped doing that after I commented out "own_window_type desktop"